# Tengo un fatal error en mi código de PHP que no logro solucionar

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de mostrar todos las noticias que hay publicadas en mi sitio, pero al momento de sacarla y recorrer el listado con un **while** me esta saltando un error muy extraño en el navegador que no logro entender. No se a que se deba este error tan extraño.

**Este es el código para sacar y recorrer la lista de artículos que hay en mi base de datos:**

```
<?php

require_once('../functions/functions.php');

// Sacar el nombre de la persona que ha iniciado sesion
$stmt = $conexion->query("SELECT *, blog.id_blog, blog.id_user_blog, blog.blog_title, blog.body, blog.description_blog, blog.foto_blog, blog.keyword, blog.credito_foto, blog.status_blog, blog.create_at_blog, users.name, users.surname, users.photo_perfil, users.sexo FROM blog INNER JOIN users ON users.id_usuario = blog.id_user_blog WHERE status_blog = 'yes' LIMIT 5");
$stmt->execute(['email' => $email]);
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

  // Los datos de la noticia
  $idBlog = $row['id_blog'];
  $title = $row['title_blog'];
  $body = $row['body'];
  $miniDescription = $row['description_blog'];
  $imagen = $row['foto_blog'];
  $keyword = $row['keyword'];
  $credito = $row['credito_foto'];
  $status = $row['status_blog'];
  $fecha = $row['create_at_blog'];

  // Datos del usuario que publicado la noticia
  $name = $row['name'];
  $surname = $row['surname'];
  $photo = $row['photo_perfil'];
  $sexo = $row['sexo'];

?>

<!-- Contenido con los card -->
<section>
    <article class="col s8">
        <a href="detail?id=1&title=titulo-del-producto">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col s12 m12 xl12">
                    <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-image">
                        <img src="../blog_foto/<?=$imagen?>" alt="<?=$title?>" class="responsive-img" />
                        <a href="profile?id=1&user=braylinpayano" data-position="top" class="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light white tooltipped" data-tooltip="<?=$name.' '.$surname?>">
                        
                        <!-- Si tiene foto de perfil, colocame la que tiene -->
                        <?php if($photo == true) : ?>
                        <img src="../photo-perfil/<?=$photo?>" class="circle" alt="<?=$name.' '.$surname?>" />

                        <!-- Si no tiene foto de perfil, colocame la por defecto -->
                        <?php else : ?>
                        <?php if($sexo == 'masculino') : ?>
                            <img src="../images/profile-masculino.png" class="circle" alt="<?=$name.' '.$surname?>" />

                            <!-- Pero si es una chica, colocame la foto por defecto para chicas -->
                        <?php else : ?>
                            <img src="../images/profile-femenina.png" class="circle" alt="<?=$name.' '.$surname?>" />
                        <?php endif ?><!-- Aqui muere el segundo if de si es chica o chico -->

                        <?php endif ?><!-- Aqui muere el primer if de si no tiene foto de perfil -->
                        
                        </a>
            </a> <!-- Final del enlace de la imagen -->
                    </div>

                    <a href="detail?id=1&title=titulo-del-producto" class="black-text">
                        <div class="card-content">
                            <h1 class="card-title"><?=$title?></h1>
                            <p class="grey-text"><?=substr($body, 0, 100).'...'?></p><br>
                            
                            <!-- Fecha -->
                            <i class="green-text">Publicado el <?=form_fecha($fecha)?></i>
                        </div>
                    </a> <!-- Final del enlace de los titulos y el precio -->

                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
    </article>
</section> <!-- Fin de un card -->

<?php } ?> <!-- Fin del While -->
```

Para hacer el código un poquito mas limpio y tratar de no tener un código spaghetti, he colocado en un archivo por separado la parte en donde saco y muestro los artículos que hay en mi base de datos y mostrándolo en la pagina donde deseo mostrarlo con un `<?php require_once('../blog_backend/news.php') ?>`

Este es el error que me esta mostrando por pantalla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu consulta SQL tiene algunas incosistencias: primero ocupas el método query en lo que parece que será una consulta que recibe valores dinámicos entonces ahi lo que procede es usar el método `prepare`, luego indicas en el execute un identificador de nombre llamado `:email` pero luego en el `WHERE` de tu consulta usas a `status_blog`; opino que empecemos por que trates esos *detalles* vuelvas a probar y nos avises si existe el mismo error o uno distinto.

Comment: `stmt` pasa a ser un booleano (seguramente un false) debido a tu metodo  `$connection->query()`. Como te dice @BetaM es muy problable que la sql (en el where) sea erronea, y por eso te devuelva un false. Luego el error es que intentas llamar a un metodo desde un bool (lo cual es incorrecto.). Te aconsejo que revises en tu `$connection` a ver si tienes algun metodo `get_errors` o que lo añadas, y lo llames despues de la consulta. Eso puede orientarte mas a ver que error te da en la query

Comment: Hay varias cosas en tu código, ya @BetaM y Jakala te han indicado algunas. Pero lo principal es tu consulta en sí: la misma es errónea sintácticamente, no puedes poner un `SELECT *`  y luego una lista de columnas: `blog.id_blog, blog.id_user_blog,` etc, o seleccionados todas (usando `*`) o indicas de forma explícita las columnas que quieres, listándolas una por una. Luego, esa consulta **no es una consulta a preparar**, ¿dónde, en la consulta, iría el parámetro para `email` que intentas pasar en el `execute()`?. Sugiero que leas en el Manual de PHP cómo funcionan las consultas preparadas.

Comment: Gracias @BetaM el problema se a solucionado colocando el `prepare` y quitando el query, pero ahora hay un nuevo problema y es que no me esta mostrando los 2 registro que tengo en la base de datos. No me muestra los registros por pantalla. El código sigue igual, solo que ahora en vez de `query` he colocado `prepare`

Comment: @BraylinIvanPayano en el where sigues teniendo entonces el problema que menciono al inicio, además me parece que a tu marcador de nombre: `email` le hacen falta al inicio los dos puntitos: `:email`.... en fin hay varios detalles, en especial también checa lo que te dice @A.Cedano

Comment: La consulta tal cual la presentas en la pregunta no puede funcionar con `prepare()`, es imposible, en esa consulta yo no veo ningún marcador, por tanto daría error si le pasas un array en el `execute()`, a no ser que hayas quitado el array que estabas pasando en el `execute()` ¿?

Comment: El problema sigue, este es el codigo `$stmt = $conexion->prepare("SELECT *, blog.id_blog, blog.id_user_blog, blog.blog_title, blog.body, blog.description_blog, blog.foto_blog, blog.keyword, blog.credito_foto, blog.status_blog, blog.create_at_blog, users.name, users.surname, users.photo_perfil, users.sexo, users.email FROM blog INNER JOIN users ON users.id_usuario = blog.id_user_blog LIMIT 5");
$stmt->execute(['email' => $email]);
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {` No me esta mostrando nada por pantalla

Comment: Esta consulta es errónea: `SELECT *, blog.id_blog, blog.id_user_blog, blog.blog_title, blog.body, blog.description_blog, blog.foto_blog, blog.keyword, blog.credito_foto, blog.status_blog, blog.create_at_blog, users.name, users.surname, users.photo_perfil, users.sexo, users.email FROM blog INNER JOIN users ON users.id_usuario = blog.id_user_blog LIMIT 5` como ya dije en anterior comentario. ¿Qué sentido tiene poner `SELECT *` seguido de una lista de columnas? Y, segundo, no puedes pasar esto con esa consulta: `$stmt->execute(['email' => $email])` porque la misma no tiene marcador.

Comment: @A.Cedano Logre solucionarlo con esta consulta `$stetament = $conexion->prepare(
    "SELECT *, users.sexo, users.name, users.surname, users.photo_perfil, users.create_at_user, blog.body, blog.title_blog, blog.keyword, blog.credito_foto, blog.foto_blog, blog.id_blog, blog.id_user_blog, blog.create_at_blog FROM blog INNER JOIN users ON users.id_usuario = blog.id_user_blog ORDER BY blog.id_blog DESC LIMIT 5"
);
$stetament->execute(array());
$result = $stetament->fetchAll();` y luego hice un `<?php foreach($result as $post) : ?>` y lo cerre de esta forma `<?php endforeach ?>` Ya lo solucione

Comment: Ya, pero así debería funcionar mejor: `$stetament = $conexion->prepare(     "SELECT * FROM blog INNER JOIN users ON users.id_usuario = blog.id_user_blog ORDER BY blog.id_blog DESC LIMIT 5" ); $stetament->execute(); $result = $stetament->fetchAll();`  Lo que he dicho ya dos veces: 1º. Si usas `SELECT *` te trae todas las columnas; 2º. Si no hay parámetros no tienes que pasar nada en `execute()`. No tiene sentido pasarle un array vacío, *por pasarle algo*.

Comment: @A.Cedano Si muchas gracias, he seguido su consejo y quiete el `*,` de mi `SELECT`. Muchas gracias por instruirme en esta parte

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pues que seguramente el problema está en que quieres hacer un execute sobre el campo $email pero puede que no haya ningún $email.

Comment: Esto no proporciona una respuesta a la pregunta. Para criticar o pedir aclaración a un autor, deja un comentario debajo de su publicación. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/242849)

Comment: No es cierto, está preguntando donde falla y yo le comento donde puede estar el error. Ergo, se puede considerar respuesta.